# How to combine 2 forms for use on the same page?

Tags: python, django

I have a UserProfile model to add extra metadata around the standard Django User model.  I am creating a registration page, and I want the user to input both the basic user information captured in the User model as well as the general profile information captured in the UserProfile model.

How can we capture and validate both of these models in one request in Django, presumably through forms?

Comment: Not an answer to the general question, but the use of a separate profile model is no longer recommended: you should create a custom User model, perhaps by extending AbstractUser. Then you'd only need one form anyway

Comment: @DanielRoseman Interesting, thanks for that.  Pretty new to Django and I was worried that using an extended User model would get in the way of my use of `python-social-auth` for authentication with 3rd party systems

Comment: You could also create a custom form with fields for both models, `User` and `Profile`, and when you manage the form in the view, you assign some fields to `User` and some other fields to `Profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is valid debate about whether to keep the User and UserProfile separated.  If you want to use separate classes:

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request, extra_context=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = AddUserForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        user_profile_form = AddUserProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(request.get_host())
            new_user_profile = user_profile_form.save(request.get_host(), new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration_complete'))
    else:
        user_form = AddUserForm()
        user_profile_form = AddUserProfileForm()

    context = {}
    return render_to_response('registration_form.html',
                            {   'user_form': user_form,
                                'user_profile_form': user_profile_form },
                            context_instance=context)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the response.  I can't find any documentation around the user_form_is_valid attribute.  I suspect you might have meant user_form.is_valid(), but even that shouldn't be an attribute on a different form.  What is the thought behind that?

Comment: Sorry, that is a ghost from some other area.  Ignore that.  Answer edited.